# How to set properties of component UserControls in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am looking for a concise snippet of example code that does the following:

From a higher level `UserControl`, I would like to change the property of an object (say a `Button`) within a sub `UserControl` via XAML.

For example, say I have a `UserControl` called `Widget` that contains a `Grid` of `Button`s. Each `Button` has a different background and border color. I then want to have a `UserControl` called `WidgetPanel` that maintains a `Grid` of `Widgets`.

For each `Widget` definition within the `WidgetPanel`, I would like to be able to set the `BorderBrush` and `Background` of each individual button (named `button0`, `button1`, `button2` respectively) property via XAML. I would also like to programmatically change those values on events from the code behind in `WidgetPanel.xaml.cs`.

Here is the XAML and the code behind for each object:

XAML for `Widget`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Widget"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Background="#FF249AA6" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="4" Background="#FFFF0046" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="4" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind for `Widget`

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class Widget : UserControl
    {
        public Widget()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML for `WidgetPanel`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.WidgetPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:Widget Grid.Column="0"/>
        <local:Widget Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind for `WidgetPanel`:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class WidgetPanel : UserControl
    {
        public WidgetPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: define some properties in `WidgetPanel` and `Widget` binding to them.

Comment: If you could provide an answer with the code that would do that from the example I gave, i would be most grateful.

Comment: Is your list of buttons inside a widget is predefined? If yes you can create desired dependency properties in `Widget` class (like `FirstButtonBorderBrush` and `FirstButtonBackground`) and bind button's properties to them as said by @LeiYang.

Comment: Could you write an answer with that worked into the code that I have provided? I have seen other comments like that and other answers that mention that but I have not found a code snippet that I can adapt to my use case. And it seems like such a simple use case straightforward but I can't figure it out.

Comment: OK, I've posted my idea. And you are right: it is simple and straightforward. But this solution is good only if list of buttons is predefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Widget` class define set of properties that affects style of inner buttons. For example, for `BorderBrush`:

```
public partial class Widget : UserControl
{
    public Widget()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // BorderBrush for first button

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstButtonBorderBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FirstButtonBorderBrush",
                                    typeof(Brush),
                                    typeof(Widget));

    public Brush FirstButtonBorderBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(FirstButtonBorderBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstButtonBorderBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    // ... repeat for other buttons
}
```

In XAML of `Widget`:

```
<Button BorderBrush="{Binding Path=FirstButtonBorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

In XAML of `WidgetPanel`:

```
<local:Widget x:Name="firstWidget"
              FirstButtonBorderBrush="Red"/>
```

Of course you can set this property from the code-behind of `WidgetPanel`:

```
firstWidget.FirstButtonBorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: I will try this out today thank you. Ill accept if it works. But wow what complicated syntax for such a simple thing right?

Comment: You will get used to it :)

Comment: Alright. I think I got it. What we're doing is not setting a get/set for the actual object, say the Button.Background which I'm modifying. Instead what it looks like we're doing is sort of redirecting the XAML keyword "Background" for a widget to a setter for a Brush object. Does that sound about right? Phew. Lol I wish there was a good comprehensive tutorial on WPF somewhere... it's cool, and the workflow is awesome when you know the tricks... but man it's hard to find answers to simple things sometimes. Thank you for your help @Maxim

Comment: how do I give an initial value from the Widget XAML? Say I want the default color to be "Black"?

Comment: @KeithL You can do it via common style for `Widget` or in `FirstButtonBorderBrushProperty` definition providing `PropertyMetadata` with default value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the below idea work. Try the below code and it may solve your query.

Wire the Focused event of Grid loaded inside a WidgetPanel UserControl in WidgetPanel.xaml.cs as below,

```
grid.Focused += Grid_Focused; //where grid is the name of Grid loaded inside a WidgetPanel user control.

private void Grid_Focused(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    //here you can get the children of grid i.e, you can get the usercontrols in Widget.xaml
    //From the user control get its children. So you can easily get the buttons here and change the respective properties.
}
```

I have just shared my opinion. I have not checked the above code. May it help you.

Comment: This is not the answer to my question but may be useful info later. Thanks.